# Combining Two Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames of different sizes and I want to add the smaller one to the larger one to update values in the larger one. The smaller DataFrame is based on a dictionary of states and their electoral votes. The larger DataFrame has a 'state' column already, with multiple rows of instances of each state as such:

```
           state                candidate  candidatevotes  totalvotes  percvotes
year                                                                            
2016  California         CLINTON, HILLARY         8753788    14181595  61.726400
2016  California         TRUMP, DONALD J.         4483810    14181595  31.617107
2016  California            JOHNSON, GARY          478500    14181595   3.374092
2016  California              STEIN, JILL          278657    14181595   1.964920
2016  California                 WRITE-IN          120739    14181595   0.851378
2016  California  LA RIVA, GLORIA ESTELLA           66101    14181595   0.466104
```

I want to combine the dictionary with this DataFrame so that each instance of the state (California in this case, but also for each state entry in the dictionary) is updated with the number of electoral votes that each state has (so there would be a new column of 'electoral_votes' with 55 in all those rows above).

The smaller DataFrame is a dictionary:

```
'California': 55,
'Texas': 38,
'Florida': 29,...
```

or alternatively I have turned it into another DataFrame:

```
                 electoral_votes
California                    55
Texas                         38
Florida                       29
```

so that it would have the form of

```
           state                candidate  ...   electoral_votes
year                                                                            
2016  California         CLINTON, HILLARY  ...          55
2016  California         TRUMP, DONALD J.  ...          55
2016  California            JOHNSON, GARY  ...          55
2016  Texas              CLINTON, HILLARY  ...          38
2016  Texas               TRUMP, DONALD J.  ...         38
2016  Texas                 JOHNSON, GARY  ...          38
```

(pared down the irrelevant lines)

I have tried concat, merge, append, join, etc, and nothing seems to work. Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a sample of the smaller df as well.

Comment: for each smaller dataframe, add a column called state. Then, `df.join` then large dataframe with the small one

Comment: you want to use `map` like this: `df_state['electoral_votes'] = df_state['state'].map(df_small.set_index('state')['electoral_votes'])`

Comment: @ScottBoston this worked! Thanks!