# Combining Pandas DataFrames With Multiple Reference Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to combine two pandas DataFrames to update the first one based on criteria from the second. Here is a sample of the two dataframes:
df1

```
year                                                                            
2016  CALIFORNIA          CLINTON, HILLARY         
2016  CALIFORNIA          TRUMP, DONALD J.         
2016  CALIFORNIA          JOHNSON, GARY          
2016  CALIFORNIA          STEIN, JILL          
2016  CALIFORNIA          WRITE-IN          
2016  CALIFORNIA          LA RIVA, GLORIA ESTELLA     
2016  TEXAS               TRUMP, DONALD J.    
2016  TEXAS               CLINTON, HILLARY    
2016  TEXAS               JOHNSON, GARY   
2016  TEXAS               STEIN, JILL         
...
           state             candidate  
year                                                                                                                                            
1988  CALIFORNIA        BUSH, GEORGE H.W.            
1988  CALIFORNIA        DUKAKIS, MICHAEL       
1988  CALIFORNIA        PAUL, RONALD ""RON""          
1988  CALIFORNIA        FULANI, LENORA  
1988  TEXAS             BUSH, GEORGE H.W.    
1988  TEXAS             DUKAKIS, MICHAEL   
1988  TEXAS             PAUL, RONALD ""RON""   
1988  TEXAS             FULANI, LENORA
```

df2

```
year                                                                            
1988  CALIFORNIA             47
1988  TEXAS                  29
...  
2016  CALIFORNIA             55
2016  TEXAS                  38
```

There are values for every election year from 2020 to 1972 that includes all candidates and all states in a similar format. There are other columns in df1 but they aren't relevant to what I'm trying to do.

My expected result is:

```
year                                                                            
2016  CALIFORNIA          CLINTON, HILLARY         55
2016  CALIFORNIA          TRUMP, DONALD J.         55
2016  CALIFORNIA          JOHNSON, GARY            55
2016  CALIFORNIA          STEIN, JILL              55 
2016  CALIFORNIA          WRITE-IN                 55
2016  CALIFORNIA       LA RIVA, GLORIA ESTELLA     55 
2016  TEXAS              TRUMP, DONALD J.          38
2016  TEXAS              CLINTON, HILLARY          38
2016  TEXAS              JOHNSON, GARY             38
2016  TEXAS              STEIN, JILL               38
...
           state             candidate  
year                                                                                                                                            
1988  CALIFORNIA     BUSH, GEORGE H.W.             47
1988  CALIFORNIA      DUKAKIS, MICHAEL             47
1988  CALIFORNIA  PAUL, RONALD ""RON""             47
1988  CALIFORNIA        FULANI, LENORA             47
1988  TEXAS     BUSH, GEORGE H.W.                  29
1988  TEXAS      DUKAKIS, MICHAEL                  29
1988  TEXAS  PAUL, RONALD ""RON""                  29
1988  TEXAS        FULANI, LENORA                  29
```

I want to match up the electoral_votes column in df2 with the year and state columns in df1 so it puts the correct value. I got some assistance and was able to match it up when there is only one column being matched (you can see the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482282/combining-two-pandas-dataframes)) but I am having trouble matching it up with the two points of reference (year and state). If I use the code linked as is it returns the error:

pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

I have tried apply, map, applymap, merge, etc and haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `left_merge`. You should specify the common columns within `on=[....]`, that the merge should be based on.

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd

# Specify two columns in the "on".
pd.merge(df1,
         df2,
         how='left',
         on=['year','state'])

Out[1821]:
 
    year       state                candidate  votes
0   2016  CALIFORNIA         CLINTON, HILLARY     55
1   2016  CALIFORNIA         TRUMP, DONALD J.     55
2   2016  CALIFORNIA            JOHNSON, GARY     55
3   2016  CALIFORNIA              STEIN, JILL     55
4   2016  CALIFORNIA                 WRITE-IN     55
5   2016  CALIFORNIA  LA RIVA, GLORIA ESTELLA     55
6   2016       TEXAS         TRUMP, DONALD J.     38
7   2016       TEXAS         CLINTON, HILLARY     38
8   2016       TEXAS            JOHNSON, GARY     38
9   2016       TEXAS              STEIN, JILL     38
10  1988  CALIFORNIA        BUSH, GEORGE H.W.     47
11  1988  CALIFORNIA         DUKAKIS, MICHAEL     47
12  1988  CALIFORNIA     PAUL, RONALD ""RON""     47
13  1988  CALIFORNIA           FULANI, LENORA     47
14  1988       TEXAS        BUSH, GEORGE H.W.     29
15  1988       TEXAS         DUKAKIS, MICHAEL     29
16  1988       TEXAS     PAUL, RONALD ""RON""     29
17  1988       TEXAS           FULANI, LENORA     29
```

The above code could be written as:

```
pd.merge(df1,
         df2,
         how='left',
         left_on=['year','state'],
         right_on=['year','state'])
```

but since the columns are the same in the 2 dfs, we can use `on = ['year', 'state']`

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around trying different combinations with ```merge``` but it never seemed to work correctly. Reading your code solution I understand better how to word it to do what I want now.

Comment: Welcome, glad it works. Please consider accepting one of the answers if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to write -

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['year', 'state'], how='left')
```

If you want to use only 3 columns from df1 -

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('<name_of_the_CSV_file>', usecols=['year', 'state', 'candidate'])
```

Comment: This also works! The second part isn't immediately relevant but it will very useful for a later part of the project I'm working on!